# Iterate through all related objects changing a value

Tags: django

I'm trying to work out a way i can iterate through each related object and change the 'show' value from True to False.

```
class Device(models.Models):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    type = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

class Log(models.Modles):
   device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='msgs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   log = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
   date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   show = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I've tried the following but it's not working.

```
device = Device.objects
for host in device.all():
    Log.objects.filter(device=host).update(show=False)
```

but i get 'Log' object has no attribute 'update'. any ideas?

Edit: Just to make it more clear what i'm trying to do. There are multiple 'Log' objects per 'Device' object. On a particular view i'd like to set the 'show' value to false because that means  they have all been read and don't need to show in the top bar of my site any more.

Comment: Is `Modles` a typo here?

Comment: Did you perhaps use `.get(..)` instead of `Filter` in reality?

Comment: ah maybe close to the solution. I tried 'get' and it errors saying that it returned 6 objects.

Comment: no, you should use `.filter(..)` but then you thus not obtain a `Log`, but a `QuerySet` of logs. So it looks like you do not provide the *full* details of your current solution.

Comment: ok i've changed it back to filter. but i'm getting the 'Log' object has no attribute 'update' again. any ideas?

Comment: @Comm4mnd0: did you change the manager of `Log`? Locally for me this works. It looks like you somehow did not share all relevant information to *reproduce* the problem.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: do you have class Log in views or else other than models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok answer is this.

```
selected_device = Device.objects.get(id.self.kwargs['device_id']
Log.objects.filter(device=selected_device).update(show=False)
```

I don't know why this works but it does. i can't see how it iterates through each log per device but it does so i'm just going to accept it works.

Comment: It doesn't iterate. It sends a single UPDATE call to the database which updates all the matching rows at once.

Comment: Ah, ok that make more sense.